# Is there an example XML document that uses every feature of XML for testing?

Tags: xml

Does anyone know where I can get a **canonical** XML document that uses every feature of the XML 1.0 specification that aren't mutually exclusive?

Not including various encoding flavors.

If I can get a single document encoded in UTF-8 that would be fine.

Comment: What do you mean by *every feature*? What is a *feature* of an XML document?

Comment: What's your use case? The obvious one - writing a parser - has probably already been done for your language. If you want, say, a stripped-down parser for an embedded system, you probably don't want to implement *every* feature of XML, just the ones you need.

Comment: @Darin every feature of XML is in the 1.0 specification.

Comment: Somewhat related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187968/fuzz-testing-xml-parser

Comment: `<comment mode="hair-splitting">` A canonical XML document can't use every XML feature, like self-closing tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible for one single document to use every feature: for example if a document uses UTF-16 encoding then it cannot also use UTF-8 encoding.

The W3C XML 1.0 Conformance Test Suite can be downloaded from http://www.w3.org/XML/Test/

Comment: obviously you can't mix encodings, I am looking for a **canonical** XML file that represents all the features that are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: which file in the hundreds of files in the conformance suite matches my requirements?

Comment: @Jarrod-Roberson: No one and all of them.